# How to create a systemd service for Rails

Tags: systemd, ruby-on-rails, systemctl

I need to create a systemd service for starting rails on my machine. Usually for running it I give the command `rails s`. But now I'd like and need to create a service for it. How could I do?

Thank you in advance for the support

Comment: Have you already tried making one based on the various examples available online?

Comment: yes but it doesn't work, I catch the error 203 /EXEC or others errors

Comment: Have you tried something like this?: https://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2015/08/26/running-a-rails-app-with-systemd-and-liking-it/

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't work..

Comment: Right, so error 203 is telling you that you are referencing a file which does not exist. Whatever script you are using you should double check both the location pointed to by the service unit, that the binary is marked as executable, and the correct spelling/location written inside the .service unit.

Comment: now, my problem is that the error 127 and it says "rails command not found"....I can't understand...

Comment: Are you certain that rails is referenced by one of your $PATH variables? If not you might need to specify its absolute location instead of calling it by name alone.

Comment: Then please show us what you currently have, how you're trying to run it, and how it exactly fails.

Comment: How could i do this? Sorry but I'm not very familiar with this

Comment: Because if I run the command "rails s" wherever I am, it works

Comment: `which rails`, and use the path that is returned for the ExecStart.

Comment: I have tried to specify all path but I get error 126 "permission denied" but the permission is 777...